# makeeditable doesnt work when setting cellFormat

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

I have a table as follows:

```
with(myTable)
{
    enableCellEditing()
    columnResizePolicy = SmartResize.POLICY
    isEditable = true
    column("Issue Date", TradeEntity::issueDate).makeEditable().cellFormat { tc ->
        style { if (tc.dayOfMonth==10) backgroundColor += Color.ORANGE }
        text = tc.toString()
    }
```

I cannot make this editable AND having a style.
It's either I have a style, either it's editable...
Any help?

**EDIT** Solved, at least in Java, I guess it's all because I didn't call `super.updateItem(it,empty)` in Kotlin

Comment: Why can't you make it? What error do you encounter?

Comment: I have no errors. The ability to edit just disappears as soon as I add `.cellFormat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cellFormat` will replace the `CellFactory` installed when you call `makeEditable()`, so they are in direct competition with each other. For that reason, TornadoFX provides `cellDecorator`, which keeps the existing `CellFactory`:

```
column("First Name", Customer::firstNameProperty) {
    makeEditable()
    cellDecorator {
        style {
            fontWeight = FontWeight.BOLD
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help Edvin, and I really like your library:)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I don't know why no answers, but I somehow managed to do it in Java thanks to 2013 Oracle tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm,and to Intellij autocompetion.
Now I have to do that in Kotlin

```
Callback<TableColumn<Person, String>, TableCell<Person, String>> cb = new Callback<TableColumn<Person, String>, TableCell<Person, String>>()
{
    @Override
    public TableCell<Person, String> call(TableColumn<Person, String> param) {


        TextFieldTableCell res = new TextFieldTableCell<Person, String>(new DefaultStringConverter()) {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(String it, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(it, empty);
                if (it == null || empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setStyle("");
                } else {
                    setText(it);
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");

                }

            }
        };
        System.out.println("callback called");
        return res;
    }
};

yourColumn.setCellFactory(cb);
```